# Wait for the finish modifications in the spreadsheet to continue the code execution when the modifications were not made using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gspread

Using *Python* and the [*gspread*](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues) module, I do this:

1. Clear values in Column A to L from the page `stack_values` and paste new values
2. Copy values in Column Z from the page `stack_values` to Column A from the page `stack_copy`

```python
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
dicter = 'client_secret.json'
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(dicter, scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet_one = client.open_by_key('spreadsheet_file_ID').worksheet('stack_values')
sheet_one.batch_clear('A1:L')
sheet_one.update('A1', new_values)

values_list = sheet_one.col_values(26)

sheet_two = client.open_by_key('spreadsheet_file_ID').worksheet('stack_copy')
sheet_two.batch_clear('A1:A')
sheet_two.update('A1', values_list)
```

In Column Z there is a formula that uses the values in columns A to L to arrive at a final result calc.

The problem with doing this is that there is a risk that Column Z will not have finished doing the calculations before doing step 2, correct?

As there is no direct option to make sure everything is 100% up to date in the spreadsheet using Python, I decided to do only the first steps with Python and the second step with the Web App via Google Apps Script:

```python
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import requests

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
dicter = 'client_secret.json'
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(dicter, scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet_one = client.open_by_key('spreadsheet_file_ID').worksheet('stack_values')
sheet_one.batch_clear('A1:L')
sheet_one.update('A1', new_values)

ok = 'go'
url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXXXXX/exec"
url = webAppsUrl + "?ok=" + ok
web_app_response = requests.get(url)
```

```javascript
function doGet(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange('stack_values!Z1:Z').copyTo(ss.getRange('stack_copy!A1'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

But reading about `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush):

> flush()
> Applies all pending Spreadsheet changes.
>
> Spreadsheet operations are sometimes bundled together to improve
> performance, such as when doing multiple calls to Range.getValue().
> However, sometimes you may want to make sure that all pending changes
> are made right away, for instance to show users data as a script is
> executing.

it led me to understand that the *flush* is linked to waiting for the end of a previous steps of the code execution in which it is inserted.

As the modifications are made outside the code, the flush placed at the beginning of the code (first task) be will work?

Comment: Whenever you do a bunch of actions to the spreadsheet and then you want to read data next from the spreadsheet try using SpreadsheetApp.flush() before performing the read

Comment: @Cooper In that case, what I'm currently doing is correct and waiting for the end of the calculations before copying them?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected goal, for example, how about the following patterns? 1. In this pattern, all processes by all scripts of python are run in Google Apps Script. But, even in this case, it might be required to wait for finishing the calculation by the formulas. 2. In this pattern, wait for finishing the calculation by the formulas in python script using `time.sleep` function. If those were not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, in this case my idea is to send the values as quickly as possible via Python but before copying the result of the calculation in Column Z, make sure that the spreadsheet calculations were done, my question really was whether ```SpreadsheetApp.flush()``` when placed at the beginning of the function it also worked or it only worked for tasks that were called before it but obligatorily within the same project in GAS.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my proposals were not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. I think that I have to study more.